# Use of checkboxes to filter a table

Tags: jquery, html

I have table with any gaps like "1st-4th"that needs to be filtered based on check boxes. 
Filters are values ​​that should sort rows with ranges into which the value falls. 
For example, a 5th filter should leave rows with values ​​like 2nd-7th, 2nd-5th, 3rd-6th. 
I have an idea to convert strings 2nd-5th to [2,3,4,5]. And set this array as an attribute of each row.
But I don’t know how to do a search with comparison and filtering. 
How to develop this idea or find a way easier and better?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="FilterForm" id="FilterForm" action="" method="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="1st" />
    <label for="filter_1">1st</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="2nd" />
    <label for="filter_2">2nd</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="3rd" />
    <label for="filter_3">3rd</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="4th" />
    <label for="filter_4">4th</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="5th" />
    <label for="filter_5">5th</label>
  </form>

  <table border="3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Class</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Name1</td>
          <td>2nd-7th</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="Name">Name2</td>
          <td>1st-3rd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="Name">Name3</td>
          <td>2nd-5th</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="Name">Name3</td>
          <td>1st-4th</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="Name">Name3</td>
          <td>3rd-6th</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Once you generate an array of values use the filter as in documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, it is best to provide [Minimal, Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please be aware of the [types of questions you should avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Here is an example. It might be more complex than you were expecting.

```js
$(function() {
  function detectRange(str) {
    var parts = str.split("-");
    return [parseInt(parts[0]), parseInt(parts[1])];
  }

  function inRange(n, r) {
    var i = r[0];
    var result = false;
    for (i; i <= r[1]; i++) {
      if (n == i) {
        result = true;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  function filterRows(fObj, tObj) {
    var rows = $("tbody > tr", tObj);
    rows.show();
    if ($(":checked", fObj).length == 0 || $(":checked", fObj).length == $("input[type='checkbox']", fObj)) {
      return;
    }
    var filter = [],
      range;
    $(":checked", fObj).each(function(i, el) {
      filter.push(parseInt($(el).val()));
    });
    rows.each(function(i, r) {
      range = detectRange($("td:last", r).text().trim());
      var hit = 0;
      $.each(filter, function(j, f) {
        if (inRange(f, range)) {
          hit++;
        }
      });
      if (hit == 0) {
        $(r).hide();
      }
    });
  }

  $("#FilterForm input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    filterRows($(this).parent(), $("table"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="FilterForm" id="FilterForm" action="" method="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="1st" />
  <label for="filter_1">1st</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="2nd" />
  <label for="filter_2">2nd</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="3rd" />
  <label for="filter_3">3rd</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="4th" />
  <label for="filter_4">4th</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="5th" />
  <label for="filter_5">5th</label>
</form>

<table border="3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Class</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>2nd-7th</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="Name">Name2</td>
        <td>1st-3rd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="Name">Name3</td>
        <td>2nd-5th</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="Name">Name3</td>
        <td>1st-4th</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="Name">Name3</td>
        <td>3rd-6th</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```